# Anyone familiar with flat soft drink production? Lemonade to be precise!

Tags: equipment, lemonade

This is a long shot but I know how crafty beer brewers are!  Currently making THC infused lemonades ( Legal State ) however the facility I now work for wants to scale up to produce approx 1875-4000 gallons per month. I am trying to solidify the beverage production process to produce a safe shelf stable product and also to figure out exactly what equipment will be required for production. This will be canned 3rd party. any help or information pertaining to this would help tremendously. Currently producing and using potassium sorbate as inhibitor however that does not kill only prevent. I assume pasteurizing is a must for this to be stable 1 year.

Comment: Yes pasteurization will definitely be required. Since it's lemonade (and therefore probably fairly low pH) you may not need a huge degree of pasteurization, but it'll really depend. Also, note that since it's being canned by a third party, this basically means they will have to have the ability to pasteurize it themselves and/or have sterile can filling capabilities (since proper pasteurization technique requires there be no down-stream steps at which further microbial contamination could occur).

Comment: I would get a pH meter and test a few existing soft drinks.  I'm no expert, but I would expect them to have a very low pH.  This can be achieved with food-grade phosphoric acid, which is used in cola.  Or citric acid if your lemonade is "fruity". Maybe you should get a consulting food scientist in.  Ref: https://www.stason.org/TULARC/science-engineering/chemistry/31-19-What-is-the-pH-of-Coca-cola.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is commercial as opposed to "home" brewing; not to mention legality questions (i.e., even if a state says it's alright, the feds probably don't).